# Creating a navigation bar in HTML (CSS)

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

When I enter the following code into a CSS style sheet, the "ul", "li" and "a" doesn't work (i.e. the font colour of it is blue). I'm trying to create a navigation bar.

```
ul  
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

li
{
    float:left;
}

a:link,a:visited
{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

a:hover,a:active
{
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: Assuming the very basic markup, your CSS works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/Ugd57/ So your HTML may be off or you may have other CSS rules overriding your styling.

Comment: It's likely that your href is off for the < link > attribute referencing your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the HTML code too, because it is possible that your `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourstylesheet.css"/>` isn't linked correctly to your stylesheet. Also, make a folder on your desktop called "Your websitename" and put the stylesheet and HTML in there because if it isn't in the same folder, it would not link.